# Angular version by code

Tags: angular, version

i know 'ng --version' to check my angular version on command line. But is there a way to get angular version in code to display it on the website ?

Comment: The duplicated question answers how to show the version of the app, this question was about the version of Angular itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can import VERSION and use it where needed:

```
import { VERSION } from '@angular/core';
```

This will give you an instance of the [Version class](https://angular.io/api/core/Version) with the current values for Angular.

Have a look at the [live demo](https://angular-version.stackblitz.io/).